# Two ViewModel Tuple

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two viewmodels. One displays employee information and the other displays information about any emergency contacts added to the employee (1-to-Many).

I am managing to display their information separately, but for some reason when I try to combine them in one view things go wrong.

At first I thought the best approach to containing all of that information in one view would be to just create 1 ViewModel and add all of the required fields. But then when I added emergency contact fields which are the "many" part of the relationship, I wasn't sure how to go about iterating through them inside same returned model (1-to-many). Because of that I tried to attempt creating a combined view using Tuple<>. Sadly, this didn't go to well either. Any help greatly appreciated.

Model Class: PersonInfoViewModel

```
public class PersonInfoViewModel
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

Model Class: EmergencyContactViewModel

```
public class EmergencyContactViewModel
{
    public int EmergencyContactId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string EmergencyContactFirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string EmergencyContactLastName { get; set; }

}
```

Model Class: CombinedView

```
public class CombinedView
{
    public Person PersonC { get; set; }
    public List<EmergencyContact> EmergencyContactsList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action: CombinedView

```
public ActionResult CombinedView(int id)
    {


        var person = _context.People.Find(id);

        ViewBag.PersonId = _context.People.Find(id);

        if (person != null)
        {
            List<EmergencyContactViewModel> ec = new List<EmergencyContactViewModel>(id);
            PersonInfoViewModel pi = new PersonInfoViewModel();
            return View(Tuple.Create(pi, ec));
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Controller Action: PersonInfo

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> PersonInfoViewModel(int? id)
    {
        var person = await db.People.FindAsync(id);// pull record from DB by id
        if (person != null)
            return View(new PersonInfoViewModel()
            {
                FirstName = person.FirstName,
                LastName = person.LastName
            });
        return View();
    }
```

Controller Action: EmergencyContactViewModel

```
    public ActionResult EmergencyContactViewModel(int? id)
    {
        List<EmergencyContact> emergecyContactsList = db.EmergencyContacts.ToList();

        List<EmergencyContactViewModel> personVmList = emergecyContactsList.Select(x =>
            new EmergencyContactViewModel
            {
                EmergencyContactId = x.EmergencyContactId,
                EmergencyContactLastName = x.EmergencyContactLastName,
                EmergencyContactFirstName = x.EmergencyContactFirstName,
            }).ToList();

        return View(personVmList);
    }
```

Comment: You should be returning a instance of `CombinedView` (and use a loop in your view to display the `EmergencyContactsList`)

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, the answer was quite simple. As Stephen has mentioned above, all I had to do was return an instance of CombinedView. In case someone else is stuck like me, this might help you:

```
    public ActionResult CombinedView(int id)
    {
        var person = _context.People.Find(id);

        ViewBag.PersonId = _context.People.Find(id);

        if (person != null)
        {
            return View(new CombinedView()
            {
                PersonC = person,
                EmergencyContactsList = new List<EmergencyContact>(person.EmergencyContacts)
            });
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Also, in the CombinedView:

```
@model [appname].Models.CombinedView
```

Additionally, it's worth noting I've tried to do repeat the same steps, but this time with the actual ViewModels as mentioned in the title of this question, but so far have failed.

```
public ActionResult CombinedView2(int id)
    {
        var person = _context.People.Find(id);

        if (person != null)
        {
            return View(new CombinedView2()
            {
                PersonInfo = new PersonInfoViewModel(),
                EmergencyContactList = new List<EmergencyContactViewModel>()
            });
        }

        return View();
    }
```